# libspotify API index parameters. 0-based or 1-based?

Tags: spotify

I have been playing around with libspotify and encountered something a bit odd. Are the index parameters to sp_playlistcontainer_move_playlist 0 based or 1 based? They seem to be both, or maybe neither :) Specifically if I have three playlists I notice the following results:

sp_playlistcontainer_move_playlist(handle, 0, 3, false)

succeeds and moves the playlist at index 0 (the first one in the list of playlist) to the end of the list of playlists.

sp_playlistcontainer_move_playlist(handle, 0, 1, false)

fails, returning SP_ERROR_INVALID_INDATA, which according to the API specs seems to indicate I am 'trying to move a folder into itself'. From that I guessed that the input (original) index is 0 based, and the target index is 1 based.  This is odd, but this

sp_playlistcontainer_move_playlist(handle, 0, 2, false)

does appear to move the first playlist (from index 0) to the second slot in the list of playlists (at what I would call index 1, but apparently is 2 according to libspotify).

Of course this also works

sp_playlistcontainer_move_playlist(handle, 2, 0, false)

so maybe the target index is not 1 based...or maybe 0 is just special cased.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 0-based.

Move operations always take indexes in the list's state BEFORE anything is done, so...

- Moving 0 to 1 will be rejected, because it's actually a no-op.
- To move the first (index 0) playlist to the second position (index 1), you actually move it to index 2, **since you want it to be after the playlist that's currently at index 1**. Once you make the call, libSpotify will "commit" the transaction by moving index 0 to be after index 1, then moving everything down one slot to fill in the vacant gap left at index 0.

Comment: So I suppose the target index is the item in the list you want it to be before, thus moving 0->1 makes no sense as 0 is already before one, but moving 0->2 makes sense as it means the item in slot 1 moves to slot 0, the item previously in slot 0 moves to slot 1 (before 2). I guess the one still odd thing is that if I move to slot 3 (i.e. at the end of the list, since index 2 is the last 'valid' index) then I get the moved callback saying the newPosition is 3, even though in reality it is 2.